# Does Babel have similar function like trivial-utf-8:write-utf-8-bytes?

Tags: utf-8, stream, lisp, common-lisp

I'm writing a HTTP server and using `trivial-utf-8:write-utf-8-bytes` to response the request. I heard [Babel](http://common-lisp.net/project/babel/) is like [trivial-utf-8](http://common-lisp.net/project/trivial-utf-8/) but more efficient, so I want to give it a try. After search for a while I can't find any similar function like `write-utf-8-bytes`. Did I misunderstand something? Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Babel has [string-to-octets](http://lispdoc.com/?q=string-to-octets), which will produce the result you need with `:encoding :utf-8`.

Comment: Then how can I write that to a stream? I tried `write-byte` but it just write one byte.

Comment: see [write-sequence](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_wr_seq.htm)

Comment: awesome! `(write-sequence (babel:string-to-octets "Hello, world!") :encoding :iso-8859-1) stream)` works like a charm!